# Display file upload message success or failure in reactjs

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am using Ajax call for upload file in server. So I want to show success & failure message as per file upload

```
  $.ajax({
  url: "https:my_url",
  data: {my data: my_data},
  method : "POST",
  success: function(result) {
    alert(result);
  },
  error: function(error){
    alert("Error in File Upload");
   }
  });
```

**And using this in react component**

```
<input id="file-input" type="file" className="fileInput" onChange=
{this.myfile} multiple />
```

**So help me out for print message as bootstrap or any good way** i.e.
 need to be as below

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
<strong>Success!</strong> You should <a href="#" class="alert-
link">File uploaded </a>.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a CSS class `invisible` like this

```
.invisible{
display:none;
}
```

And then have a state variable `uploaded` with initial value anything say `uploading`

```
this.state = {uploaded:'uploading'}
```

Then create the two alert messages

```
<div className=`alert alert-success ${this.state.uploading === 'success'?'':'invisible'}`>
<strong>Success!</strong> You should <a href="#" class="alert-
link">File uploaded </a>.

<div className=`alert alert-danger ${this.state.uploading === 'failure'?'':'invisible'}`>
<strong>Failure!</strong> Failed <a href="#" class="alert-
link">File uploaded </a>.
</div>
```

What is happening here is that the success message only gets displayed when `this.state.uploading` is equal to 'success' and the failure message when it is equal to 'failure'.

And then in the `ajax` call

```
 $.ajax({
  url: "https:my_url",
  data: {my data: my_data},
  method : "POST",
  success: (result) => {
     this.setState({uploading:'success'})
  },
  error: (error) => {
     this.setState({uploading:'failure'})
   }
  });
```

The `ajax` call sets the `this.state.uploading` to success or failure depending on the result of the `ajax` call and the appropriate message is displayed.

For ES5 style

```
 var _this = this
 $.ajax({
  url: "https:my_url",
  data: {my data: my_data},
  method : "POST",
  success: function (result) {
     _this.setState({uploading:'success'})
  },
  error: function (error) {
     _this.setState({uploading:'failure'})
   }
  });
```

Comment: Okay I'm trying to implement then let you know for the same.

Comment: getting error in console & also not prompt message in screen:    
Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Comment: Could you post the entire Component code so I can have a look?

Comment: Check this link & let me know if still need any help regarding code https://jsfiddle.net/HimFiddle90/d4xnqkg1/1/

Comment: Oh ok. The error happens cause within the `success` and `error` functions the `this` changes. You can use ES6 style functions to remove the error. I'll modify in original answer. For ES5 style you'll need to keep a reference to the `this` in another variable.

Comment: Still didn't getting any message on the screen for success or failure.

Comment: Have you added the Es6 style functions? Also the `.invisible` class in CSS? Also I see an error in your fiddle.

`<div className={"alert" + this.state.uploading === 'success'? 'alert-succes' : 'invisible'}>`

is wrong as there is no gap after `alert` so the CSS class will be `alertalert-success` or `alertinvisible`. So add a gap there.

`<div className={"alert " + this.state.uploading === 'success'? 'alert-success' : 'invisible'}>`

Comment: yes I have removed the space but still not rendering any message.

Comment: What class is there on the `alert`. Could you use WebTools/Inspector to check the DOM?

Comment: class="invisible"

Comment: On both the alerts? It should be on just one.

Comment: But in that case always message is rendering ... which is not good. requirement is that when we upload then need to be render message according action.

Comment: How is it always rendering? The `state.uploaded` is only `success` or `failure` after upload. Before that it is `uploading` hence both the divs will be `invisible`. Post the upload only one will be `invisible`.